# I want to read how many people have seen my post in my facebook page using restfb in java

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

Using the code below I was able to read how many reactions (in detailed) my posts in my Facebook page have received.
https://restfb.com/cookbook/
Now I need to read how many people have seen the posts specially I need to limit the date. For example: how many people have seen my post with the id x, yesterday?  I do not need list of people, just how many people have seen and also how many people have clicked to open in case there was a picture.
Based on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/seen/ I wrote the code below:
My code :

```
int postNumber=0
 Connection<Post> results = fbclient.fetchConnection(pageID + "/feed", Post.class);
           for(List<Post> mypage: results) {
            for(Post posted: mypage) {
              postNumber++;
              String postID=posted.getId();
              Post hasSeen=fbclient.fetchObject(postID+"/seen",Post.class, Parameter.with("fields", 
               "seen_time, total_count"));
                System.out.println("post number "+ postNumber+ "has been seen by "+ hasSeen);
        }}
```

The error is :

```
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (seen) on node type (PagePost) (code 100, subcode null) 'null - null'
    at com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:174)
    at com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:61)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:794)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:721)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:683)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObject(DefaultFacebookClient.java:276)
```

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: `postid/seen`  is only available for workplace apps. This means for the company version of Facebook. You should check the post insights: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#page-posts

Comment: Thanks a million. now i am using
 Connection<Insight> insights = fbclient.fetchConnection(pageID + "/insights", Insight.class, Parameter.with("metric", "page_posts_impressions_unique")); 
and it returns me a list of json files: List<JsonObject>, my results are as follows:
[{"value":1,"end_time":"2020-08-17T07:00:00+0000"}, {"value":1,"end_time":"2020-08-18T07:00:00+0000"}]
[{"value":4,"end_time":"2020-08-19T07:00:00+0000"}, {"value":3,"end_time":"2020-08-20T07:00:00+0000"}]

Comment: why I have 2 "value" in each row of my json objects? which value is the answer for page_posts_impressions_unique ?

Comment: it looks like the values are for one day each and the end_time is the day, at least the end_time values suggest this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String accessTokenFB= "write your access token";
         //System.out.println("accessTokenFB is "+ accessTokenFB);
        FacebookClient fbclient=new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenFB, Version.VERSION_7_0);
        String postID="write your facebook post id";
        JsonObject jObj=fbclient.fetchObject(postID + "/insights", JsonObject.class,Parameter.with("metric", "post_clicks, post_impressions"));
        //System.out.println(jObj);
        JsonValue data=jObj.get("data");
//      System.out.println(data);
        JsonValue post_clicks=((JsonObject) ( (JsonArray) data).get(0)).get("name");
        System.out.println(post_clicks.asString()); 
        JsonValue valueClick= ((JsonObject) ((JsonArray) ((JsonObject) ((JsonArray) data).get(0)).get("values")).get(0)).get("value");
        System.out.println(valueClick.asInt()); 
        
        JsonValue post_impressions=((JsonObject) ( (JsonArray) data).get(1)).get("name");
        System.out.println(post_impressions.asString());
        JsonValue valueImpressions= ((JsonObject) ((JsonArray) ((JsonObject) ((JsonArray) data).get(1)).get("values")).get(0)).get("value");
        System.out.println(valueImpressions.asInt());
```

Comment: You can use the `asArray` and the `asObject` method on the JsonValue and remove the casts ;)